# AngularJS - Find Element by Attribute Value

Tags: angularjs, dom

I'm trying to use AngularJS to query the DOM of my view. I need to get all of the elements that have the attribute 'data-placement' with the value of 'top'. In jQuery, I would do this:

```
var elements = $('[data-placement="top"]');
```

However, I don't know how to do it with AngularJS. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: AngularJS doesn't do this. jQuery does this. Load jQuery in your application and it should work

Comment: That's not entirely true: you can do this with custom directives, which would be the "Angular" way of doing things. Can you post a bit more information about your use case?

Comment: A golden rule of Angular development is to never, ever touch the DOM from the controller. So to answer your question with a few questions: Where are you placing this javascript code, and what are you planning to do with these elements? If this code goes anywhere else than in a custom directive, you may want to step back and think about doing this another way.

Answer (score 6):

In AngularJS you won't do direct DOM manipulation from the controller, you should create a directive to to that. Inside the directive you can use JQuery as you wish.

Anyway you I think you can use `angular.element()` with a JQlite selector, here's the documentation of [angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element).

Example:

```
// find('#id')
angular.element(document.querySelector('#id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand that you wanted to find elements with atrributes requiring certain condition in that case we can use `$document`.

You can find more info about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document).

So coming to your requirement, you can find it by.

```
$document.find("[attribute-name='attribute-value')");
```

That will return the element object wrapped in jQuery or jqLite. But to use it you need to inject `$document` into your controller. So you continue angular related operations with it.

Another approach to this is `angular.element`.

```
angular.element.find("[attribute-name='attribute-value')");
```

But this will return element with wrapped raw DOM element or HTML string as a jQuery element. you can find more info about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

I prefer to use `$document` as Angular operations can be done using the first method.