# How to use the child element's attrs in ngShow?

Tags: angularjs

I wanna check if an element's child has a class name in it's `ngShow` directive like

```
<div ng-show="check here if the child img has class name 'active'">
    <img class="...">
</div>
```

How to do it?

**EDIT**

What i did try so far is writing a function for it like those

```
<div ng-show="test(this)">....

<div ng-show="test($event)">....
```

And when i apply `console.log` for those parameters in `test` function i have some object that i didnt understand what it stands for for `this` and i have `undefined` for `$event` which i know i can use in `ng-click` but obviously not here.

Comment: Some basic code to demonstrate some effort on your part to solve this already would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you use to add the class name 'active' to the image? Can't you use the same condition on the ng-show?

Comment: As localhost said, it would be good to see more context for this question. @BatuZet, check out the help page for [_How do I ask a good question?_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (Also, localhost is an awesome username)

Comment: child of what? We don't have crystal balls. Everything in angular hinges on your data models and you have shown none. Also you are looking at this backwards, you want the property in the data that triggers `active`

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be worth it to take a look at [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

However, to answer your question,

- I created an [example PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/TYTgVu5Dzor2UiRvKRnv?p=preview)

  - It answers your original question, before you changed it to checking if the element's child has the class.
  - However, the same principles apply, so I'll provide my answer.
- **It is worth noting that it's probably better practice to accomplish this using a directive.**
- EDIT: I'd also like to second @charlietfl's comment. I think you may be approaching this issue backwards.

That being said, here is one solution:

#### HTML

```html
<!-- remove 'active' from class, and element is no longer shown -->
<div id="special" ng-show="showElem" class="active">ACTIVE</div>
```

#### JS (Controller)

```js
// get the element we want to test
var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('#special'));
// check if that element has the class 'active'
$scope.showElem = elem.hasClass('active');  // true or false
```

---

Another way to do it would be:

```
<div id="special" ng-show="elem.hasClass('active');" class="active">ACTIVE</div>
```

and

```
$scope.elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('#special'));
```

---

#### Resources

- AngularJS documentation for:

  - [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)
  - [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)
- Relevant SO Questions

  - [AngularJS - Find Element by Attribute Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636537/angularjs-find-element-by-attribute-value)
  - [How to check if element has class with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192705/how-to-check-if-element-has-class-with-angularjs)